# How can I use nested subqueries to find out the name of products that are ordered by a specific customer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, single-page-application

So I’m using oracle application express, I’m having trouble with the query so far. I keep getting a error that the query did not end properly. I understand that you need to input parenthesis in the right places.  Maybe I’m not getting that right? Anyway I feel like I have the concept/body but something is slightly off. I need to use at least 3 subqueries.  Here’s the nested query:

```
SELECT PI.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO PI 
(
SELECT OI.PRODUCT_ID 
FROM DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS
(
SELECT O.ORDER_ID 
FROM DEMO_ORDERS
(
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID 
FROM DEMO_CUSTOMERS WHERE IN (‘Willam Hartsfield’)
```

So I’m not really sure what’s wrong but it is really frustrating. P.S. I’m new to all this.

Comment: Where are your closing parenthesis ?

Answer (score 0):

> to find out the name of products that are ordered by a specific
>   customer

You don't need "nested subqueries", what you do need are `JOINS`.

The `orders` table will have a column that identifies which `customer`, the `order_items` table will identify which `order number` each item refers to, and it will also identify which `product number` as well. So we want to JOIN this information together, I will start by re-arranging your SQL (quite a bit)

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM DEMO_CUSTOMERS C
inner join DEMO_ORDERS O        on C.?? = O.??
inner join DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS OI  on O.?? = OI.??
inner join DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO PI on OI.?? = PI.??

SELECT PI.PRODUCT_NAME  FROM  PI 
SELECT O.ORDER_ID 
SELECT OI.PRODUCT_ID FROM 

WHERE IN ('Willam Hartsfield')
;
```

So, having re-arranged the tables a quite a lot I have some unknowns to solve (the question marks) what column names exist in those tables that would allow me to join them together, and as I don't know all of these some are guesses:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID
FROM DEMO_CUSTOMERS C
inner join DEMO_ORDERS O        on C.ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
inner join DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS OI  on O.ID = OI.ORDER_ID
inner join DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO PI on OI.PRODUCT_ID = PI.ID
```

So: Customer > Order > Order Items > Product Info are now "related" to each other through `joins`

Now the where clause needs fixing, i.e.

```
WHERE some-column-name-here IN ('Willam Hartsfield')
```

Something like his:

```
WHERE C.NAME IN ('Willam Hartsfield')
```

Note you could also just use: `WHERE C.NAME = 'Willam Hartsfield'`

Now all we should need now are the extra columns, making sure we include the table aliases when we do this:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, O.ORDER_ID, OI.PRODUCT_ID, PI.PRODUCT_NAME
FROM DEMO_CUSTOMERS C
inner join DEMO_ORDERS O        on C.ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
inner join DEMO_ORDER_ITEMS OI  on O.ID = OI.ORDER_ID
inner join DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO PI on OI.PRODUCT_ID = PI.ID
WHERE C.NAME IN ('Willam Hartsfield')
```

This should be closer to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution saying nested queries. The queries were missing right parenthesis. This can be done by formatting the query.

**-- For nested queries**

```
SELECT product_name FROM demo_product_info WHERE product_id IN 
(
SELECT product_id FROM demo_order_items WHERE order_id IN 
(SELECT order_id FROM demo_orders WHERE customer_id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_id FROM demo_customers WHERE cust_name IN ('Willam Hartsfield')))
);
```

Also, as mentioned @User_by_Already the best solution would be writing to join clause on the tables.

**-- JOIN queries**

```
SELECT 
    dpi.product_name 
FROM    
    demo_customers dc, demo_orders do, 
    demo_order_items doi, demo_product_info dpi 
WHERE 
    dc.customer_id  =   do.customer_id 
AND do.order_id     =   doi.order_id 
AND doi.product_id  =   dpi.product_id 
AND dc.cust_name    IN ('Willam Hartsfield');
```